# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

I am trying to use Angular's POST and PUT methods but I keep getting the error:

`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`

My code:

```
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:4567/api/v1/project",
            data: project_data
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }),
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error!');
            console.log(response);
        }


       $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: "http://localhost:4567/api/v1/project/1",
            data: data
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }),
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error!');
            console.log(response);
        }
```

Does anyone know what might be going on or how to fix it? Other solutions I've found involve changes to the server side code (in this instance, I don't have access to the server). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should pass actual id instead of `:id` in the URL, better you can think of to use `$resource` library

Comment: hi - I tried passing in the actually `:id` parameter, but I'm still getting the same error..

Comment: What sort of server are you running?

Comment: Is CORS enabled on server? Do GET requests work?

Comment: The server is Spark. I'm not sure if CORS is enabled on the server. GET requests didn't work until I installed the CORS add on

Answer (score 0):

If you use Node.js, just do this:

```
app.options('/api/v1/project/1', function(req, res, next) {  
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Accept,X-Requested-With");  
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");   
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");  
    res.status(204);//important
    res.end()
});
app.put('/api/v1/project/1', function(req, res, next) {
    ...your normal code here
})
```